# How to generate Grothendieck Topologies from families of sieves

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category with pullbacks, a basis for a Grothendieck topology on $\mathcal{C}$ is a function which assigns to each object $C$ a collection $K(C)$ of families of morphisms with codomain $C$ such that:

$(A)$ if $f: C' \to C$ is an isomorphism, then $\{f: C' \to C\} \in K(C)$;

$(B)$ if $\{f_i: C_i \to C\} \in K(C)$, then for any morphism $g: D \to C$ the family of pullbacks $\{\pi_2: C_i \times_C D \to D \mid i \in I\}$ belongs to $K(D)$;

$(C)$ if $\{f_i: C_i \to C\} \in K(C)$ and if for each $i \in I$ one has a family $\{g_{ij}: D_{ij} \to C_i \mid j \in I_i\} \in K(C_i)$, then the family of composites $\{f_i \circ g_{ij}: D_{ij} \to C \mid \, i \in I, j \in I_i\}$ belongs to $K(C)$.

Now, if $K$ is a basis on $\mathcal{C}$, it generates a topology $J$ by

$$
S \in J(C) \iff \exists R \in K(C) \,\, R \subseteq S
$$

At this point, as pointed out by Borceux (Handbook of Categorical Algebra, Vol. 3), Grothendieck topologies on $\mathcal{C}$ form a locale, and meet agrees with the usual set-thereotic intersection of Grothendieck topologies. This means that whenever we have a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of sieves on an object $C$, we can construct the smallest Grothendieck topology containing it. But, which is such a closure?

Clearly, we must first add the maximal sieve, if it does not belong to $\mathcal{S}$. But, how to continue such a construction?

Here, I found something:

[Description of generated Grothendieck topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578691/description-of-generated-grothendieck-topology)

But I don't know if it answers to the general problem.

Comment: Well, there is an obvious construction, given by just iteratively adding all the needed sieves according to rules (A), (B), and (C).  Are you looking for something simpler than that?

Comment: Similarly to what happens for instance for set-theoretic union closed families, where an element of the closure is expressed as the union of the members in the generating family, is there some way to describe the sieves in the "Grothendieck closure" in a simple way, such as: the class of morphisms such that (satisfy these properties) ?